# How can I test for XML using jQuery

Tags: jquery, xml

How can I test for XML using jQuery?

I have a bookmarklet that needs to know whether the current page is XML. How can I check for this?

I imagine I will pass in the document and check for the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

But not sure.

Comment: Why do you need to know?

Comment: Because XML doesn't have a document.body I can append stuff to. Instead, I'm now just checking for a body and if one doesn't exist I warn the user.

Answer (score 8):

Not sure if you want to load the page again, but you could run it through [`jQuery.parseXML()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/), which will throw an exception for invalid XML, so you could just try to parse the page and if no exception is thrown then it is (valid) XML.

For example:

```
var xml = "<rss version='2.0'><brokenxml></rss>";
try {
    xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml);
} catch (err) {
    // was not XML
}
```

Comment: Thanks - Can a normal web page be successfully parsed though as valid XML?

Comment: Hmm good question, you can certainly create web pages that are valid XML (this is what XHTML was all about) however a page with valid mark-up is not necessarily also valid XML. You could get the page source with `document.documentElement.outerHTML` (plain JavaScript)

Comment: I managed to find $('html')[0].innerHTML in the firebug console after passing $('html') to console.log. Doing document.documentElement.outerHTML doesn't seem to work for me. Just get undefined. Anyway not much use for finding out whether a doc is XML.